# How do I publish my forms app to the internet?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have created a forms application on Visual Studio 2017. I have a website that I want the public to download my app for windows. On the site, I have a download button but I don't know how to make it so when the download button is pressed, the application can begin downloading. I don't care if it is through a setup.exe. How could I do this?

Comment: You ask a few things: what files are necessary for running, how to store them on the site, etc. Please focus your question.

Comment: You could use `ClickOnce`. Search it on internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean auto-download when user press download button on your website built on engine different from ASP.NET?

You need to place link directly to your file:

```html
<a href="http://[yourwebsite]/download/setup.exe"><!-- your some code here --></a>
```